# Azure Cognitive Search: Searching for Data Containing a "-"

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have a customer creating a search application.  They have a unique identifier for each document, outside of the Id field, that they search on regularly.  That field happens to contain dashes.  The only way we've found to uniquely search the index for a given document using this field is by prefixing it with the field name and enclosing it in quotes similar to the following:

EventId:"TSA-12-01112-15"

In other words, searching for either:

TSA-12-01112-15

or

"TSA-12-01112-15"

returns multiple results where it appears that each segment of field that is separated by a "-" is being returned as a separate token by the analyzer.  We're using the standard.lucene analyzer on the field in question.

Is this expected behavior?  Is there any way to work around this so that a simple phrase search, without the field name, shown above will return the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

The standard lucene analyzer considers `-` as a delimiter and produces each part as a separate token. Judging from your explanation, your usecase demands an exact match. You can use the [keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers#AnalyzerTable) analyzer for this field and then pass the text as is with dashes.

The keyword analyzer produces a single token for the entire text and is a good option for identifiers and codes. One limitation is that the query text should match the field text exactly. For ex.

`EventId:TSA-12-01112-15` will match the docs where text in `EventId` is exactly`TSA-12-01112-15`

In addition if your query patterns are heavily skewed towards exact matches and their relative ordering is not important, consider using filter expressions which are optimized for this.